# The request body is too large and exceeds the maximum permissible limit when generating sas token

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I am using the below script to generate sas token using bash

```
sas_token=$(curl https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$subscription_id/resourceGroups/$rg_name/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/$storage_account/listServiceSas/?api-version=2017-06-01 -X POST -d "{\"canonicalizedResource\":\"/blob/$storage_account/$sa_container\",\"signedResource\":\"c\",\"signedPermission\":\"rcw\",\"signedProtocol\":\"https\",\"signedExpiry\":\"$(date -d '+30 minutes' +%FT%TZ)\"}" -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" | jq -r '.serviceSasToken')
```

when i try to upload a large file which is 500mb it gives me the below error
The request body is too large and exceeds the maximum permissible limit. 67108864

generated sas token from the above script is :

```
sv=2015-04-05&sr=c&spr=https&se=2021-04-09T06%3A22%3A19.0000000Z&sp=racwdl&sig=xxxx
```

When i generate a sas token from azure portal i get it as below

```
sp=racwdl&st=2021-04-09T05:54:16Z&se=2021-04-09T13:54:16Z&spr=https&sv=2020-02-10&sr=c&sig=xxxx
```

here if you notice the sv that is signedversion is 2020-02-10 and with this sas token i am able to upload large files.

So i noticed that in both the above sas token the sv is different so i tried to add signedversion in my code like below

```
sas_token=$(curl https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$subscription_id/resourceGroups/$rg_name/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/$storage_account/listServiceSas/?api-version=2017-06-01 -X POST -d "{\"canonicalizedResource\":\"/blob/$storage_account/$sa_container\",\"signedResource\":\"c\",\"signedPermission\":\"rcw\",\"signedProtocol\":\"https\",\"SignedVersion\":\"2020-02-10\",\"signedExpiry\":\"$(date -d '+30 minutes' +%FT%TZ)\"}" -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" | jq -r '.serviceSasToken')
```

but it still generates an sv with 2015-04-05 and not with what i specified.

can you please tell how to solve this issue

Comment: @FrankGong Still the same issue

Comment: Could you please try to use [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-user-delegation-sas-create-cli#create-a-user-delegation-sas-for-a-container) to generate `sas` token.

Comment: @FrankGong the problem is we cant have az cli in the prod server so we need to do it using api itself

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anything you can do as far as changing the signed version parameter.

My guess is that the implementation to generate SAS via Storage Resource Provider API makes use of Storage REST API version `2015-04-05` (signed version parameter) and if you look at [`request body parameters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/storageaccounts/listservicesas#request-body), you will notice that there's no parameter to specify the signed version parameter in the request.

One thing you could do is change your upload implementation and upload your large blob in chunks where the size of each chunk is less than or equal to 64 MB.

FWIW, the block size limit was changed from 64 MB to 100 MB in Storage Service version 2016-05-31: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/version-2016-05-31.

Comment: can you tell me how to brask into chunks and upload? I am using bash

Comment: Unfortunately I wouldn't know. Can you edit your question and include your upload code. I can try :).